# Empty list not appending

Tags: python, list, readline

I am trying to get a list of positive words and negative words with my code but it keeps giving me an empty list. Also I'd like to know how to make my text all lowercase so it can properly append to the positive and negative lists which are all lower case.

```
def main():
    text = open ('dataset.csv','r').read()
    SC = [ ',' , '.' , '”' , '’' , '"' , "'"  , '?' , '!' , '&', '@', '*' , '#' ]
    for i in SC:
        text = ''.join(text.split(i))
        text.replace (i,'')
    
    outfile = open ('dataset_new.csv','w')
    outfile.write(text)
    outfile.close()
    infile = outfile = open ('dataset_new.csv','r')
    pos_words = []
    neg_words = []
    count = 0
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print (line)
        print ('Your positive words are', pos_words)
        print ('There are', len(pos_words), 'positive words in this text')
        print ('Your negative words are', neg_words)
        print ('There are', len(neg_words), 'negative words in this text')
        count+=1
    positive_txt = open('positives.txt','r')
    negative_txt = open('negatives.txt','r')
    positive_list = pos_list(positive_txt)
    negative_list = neg_list(negative_txt)
    pos_words = positivewords(lines, pos_words, positive_list)
    neg_words = negativewords(lines, neg_words, negative_list)
def pos_list(positive_txt):
    data = positive_txt.read()
    positive_list = data.replace('\n','.').split('.')
    return positive_list
def neg_list(negative_txt):
    data = negative_txt.read()
    negative_list = data.replace('\n','.').split('.')
    return negative_list
def positivewords(lines, pos_words, positive_list):
    w = len(positive_list)
    for i in range(w):
        if positive_list[i] in lines:
                pos_words.append(positive_list[i])
    i+=1
    return pos_words
def negativewords(lines, neg_words, negative_list):
    w = len(negative_list)
    for i in range(w):
        if negative_list[i] in lines:
                neg_words.append(negative_list[i])
    i+=1
    return neg_words
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ur running into trouble because you're using lists.

try something like this:

```
import csv
SC = { ',' , '.' , '”' , '’' , '"' , "'"  , '?' , '!' , '&', '@', '*' , '#' }
    
def main():
    filename = input("Enter the filename: ")
    sub = filename + ".txt"
    infile = open(sub, 'r')
    out_file = open ("NewFile3.csv", 'w')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, FIELDS)
    writer.writeheader()
 
    data1 = {}
    data2 = {}
    data3 = {}
```

Basically just put everything in dictionaries like your positive and negative and then convert/append to a final dictionary or list.
Also in regards to making it lowercase u can just take your final string output and say ".lower())"

so say:

```
x = "STACK OVERFLOW"

print(x.lower())  # would output "stack overflow"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not analyse your code in detail, but your list is empty because you initialize it as empty and don't change it before printing.

Check that these lines initializes your lists as empty:

```
...
pos_words = []
neg_words = []
...
```

Then you print the content of these lists without making any change to them.

I think you probably want to move the piece of code that prints the content of the lists (the code below) to the end of `main()` function:

```
# move this code to the end of main() function
for line in lines:
    print (line)
    print ('Your positive words are', pos_words)
    print ('There are', len(pos_words), 'positive words in this text')
    print ('Your negative words are', neg_words)
    print ('There are', len(neg_words), 'negative words in this text')
    count+=1
```

Finally, if you want to make a string lowercase, just use the `lower` function.  As this example:

```
def pos_list(positive_txt):
    data = positive_txt.read().lower()
    positive_list = data.replace('\n','.').split('.')
    return positive_list
```

Notice the `.lower()` function call in the first line.

---

I made a full solution so you can check what's wrong with your code:

##### dataset.txt

```
You are cool!
He is uglY.
Is she pRetty? I think she is bad.
Ok, this dog is a bad guy.
How pretty?!
```

##### positives.txt

```
cool
pretty
```

##### negatives.txt

```
ugly
bad
```

##### main.py

```
import re

DATASET_FILE = 'dataset.txt'
POSITIVEWORDS_FILE = 'positives.txt'
NEGATIVEWORDS_FILE = 'negatives.txt'

def main():
    with open(POSITIVEWORDS_FILE, 'r') as positivefile:
        positive_words = positivefile.read().split()

    with open(NEGATIVEWORDS_FILE, 'r') as negativefile:
        negative_words = negativefile.read().split()

    positive_found = []
    negative_found = []

    with open(DATASET_FILE,'r') as dataset:
        for line in dataset:
            # remove all non alphanumeric chars (except spaces and "-")
            words = re.sub('[^\w\s-]', '', line).lower().split()

            for word in words:
                if word in positive_words:
                    positive_found.append(word)

                if word in negative_words:
                    negative_found.append(word)

    # remove duplicates from the list turning the list into a set
    unique_positivewords = set(positive_found)
    unique_negativewords = set(negative_found)

    print(f'Your positive words are {list(unique_positivewords)}.')
    print(f'There are {len(positive_found)} positive words in this text.')
    print(f'Your negative words are {list(unique_negativewords)}.')
    print(f'There are {len(negative_found)} negative words in this text.')

main()
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the lower function and i moved the position of.                                 
for line in lines:
    print (line)
    print ('Your positive words are', pos_words)
    print ('There are', len(pos_words), 'positive words in this text')
    print ('Your negative words are', neg_words)
    print ('There are', len(neg_words), 'negative words in this text')
    count+=1.     However, I am still getting an empty list. I initialized it as empty because I wanted an empty list that could be appended to and its still not appending properly. I tried to append in the functions.

Comment: @SemiOlujobi Well... you should expect anyone to teach you how to code or to find every single error in your code. This is a Q&A site and your question looks rude for the community. People expect that you demonstrate a real effort in trying to solve your own problem, with research and an history to what you did to solve, not just a piece of broken code. However, since you're a new contributor and I like to be cool, I edited my question with a full solution for your problem. Check if it is what you want and if it helps you to understand where you made a mistake. Be welcome. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I apologize if my question came off as rude. That was not my intention. I appreciate the help again.